# VSCode, how to go back up the source tree after following declarations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By using ctrl-click on a symbol, VSCode will open the source file and take you to that symbol.  If you continue to walk through the code this way, such as going up the constructor heirarchy, is it possible reverse your steps?  e.g., in Eclipse, you would use the arrows in the toolbar:

```
*<- <- -> ->*
```

Where the asterisks would take you to the last/next edit and the arrows without would take you back through the navigation stack.

Closest I've found is Alt-arrow but that is not what I want for walking through code declarations.

Thanks.

Edit:
I should point out that the navigation to source I'm referring to includes opening source that's attached to a Maven dependency.  I do see partial symbol navigation with "navigationBack" but it's not accurate when walking code across split editors or attached source.

Comment: If you only don't want to use that specific key to navigate to the previous declaration you can just bind the command `workbench.action.navigateBack
` command to a custom key

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `Go Back` command (`workbench.action.navigateBack`) for this. It is [bound to](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> by default.

The corresponding `Go forward` command navigates forward: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: That's the command mapped to Alt-[ l | r ]arrow, perhaps because I'm using the Eclipse keymap, but this doesn't walk the navigation stack.  At least, not when the files are not in the source tree.  Question edited to point out the particular use case, in case that's relevant.

Comment: I don't understand your expected behavior then. Is the issue that navigateBack includes non-symbol locations?

Comment: No, it's that is skips symbols in files that are not in the source tree.  If I open a declaration in a jar and then open a declaration from there to another declaration in a jar, then navigate back down the stack, the cursor skips those intermediate files and jumps all the way back to my source file.